# Get count of value row

Tags: mysql, count

I'm trying to figure out what MySQL code would do the following.

Count * from 'users' table (eg; 0,7 rows) then within the count get the count of 'money' based on the value of the user. I'm struggling to explain, so I hope that I've gave as much detail, 1 more example below.

I'm trying to achieve this:

You are currently the eg *1st, 2nd (depending on money value).* richest person on the website.

database example:

```
-------------------------------
 id  | username  | money
-------------------------------
 1   | name      | 1000
 2   | name2     | 3000
-------------------------------
```

Comment: So you are after a ranking, like [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188311/how-to-find-rank-of-row-in-mysql), or a more complete and [simpler example](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#460). Feel free to answer yourself.

Comment: in your example, you want the name2 person first, as they have more money than name?

Comment: I know how to get the highest value of a row, I just don't understand how to get COUNT of how rich the user is, lets say I have a user named name2, and he has 5000, and 3 other users have 5000+ I'd like it to say you are the 4th richest by counting the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of getting the rankings:

> ```
> select version();
> ```
>
> ```
> | version() |
> | :-------- |
> | 8.0.13    |
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE person( name CHAR(10), money INT );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO person VALUES
>   ('Smith',10),('Jones',15),('White',20),
>   ('Black',40),('Green',50),('Brown',20);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT name, money, rank() OVER(win) AS 'Richest'
> FROM person
> WINDOW win AS (ORDER BY money DESC);
> ```
>
> ```
> name  | money | Richest
> :---- | ----: | ------:
> Green |    50 |       1
> Black |    40 |       2
> White |    20 |       3
> Brown |    20 |       3
> Jones |    15 |       5
> Smith |    10 |       6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5159f723ba549fd56f6f06a9c6199600)*

Note this code is for MySQL-8.0 or MariaDB-10.2+. For [earlier version implementations see this example](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=460)

To get a value for a single user:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 AS "Richest"
FROM person p
JOIN person richer
  ON p.money < richer.money
WHERE p.name="Brown"
```

This doesn't have any version requirements.

Ref [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c85cfd9c598c7ff0b822cb381b029d02).

Comment: Infact, it doesn't seem to work when I run this code.`SELECT username, money, rank() OVER(win) AS 'Richest' FROM users WHERE username = 'lizzy' WINDOW win AS (ORDER BY money DESC)` Lizzy is the second highest and it displays shes first by that code..

Comment: Added. Please include a more complete example next time initially including sample input and expected output.

Comment: You're an absolute legend, thank you very much.